# NumberPicker inside AlertDialog java

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, builder, numberpicker

I'm trying to get a numberpicker inside an alertdialog but it returns me the following error:

> 12-22 20:37:09.640 16893-16893/com.example.asus.mingausfashionmoda
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

here 
`at com.example.asus.mingausfashionmoda.estoque$2$2.onItemClick(estoque.java:134)`

This is where I create the AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(estoque.this);
builder.setTitle("ADICIONAR OU REMOVER ROUPA");
NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.nPicker);
np.setMinValue(0);
np.setMaxValue(5);
builder.setView(np);


builder.setPositiveButton("ADICIONAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        adicionarR(objectIdTXTtoS);
    }
});
builder.setNegativeButton("REMOVER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {@Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        removerR(objectIdTXTtoS);
    }
});
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

This is what I have on (`estoque.java.134`):

```
dialog.show();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. Have you tried to look for libraries? https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers

Comment: Yeah that's not exactly what I need, I would like to see my project working and also this is a date dialog, I need only one number because I'll use it to save some data :D But thanks

Comment: No problem. However it does contain a pure numberpicker dialog, which is also shown in the screenshots.

Comment: All you need is a [custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout)